# Configuring protocol buffer in windows

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am trying to install the google protocol buffer in windows, the instructions first as me this:

---

1. cd' to the directory containing the package's source code and type
    './configure' to configure the package for your system.  If you're
    using 'csh' on an old version of System V, you might need to type
    'sh ./configure' instead to prevent 'csh' from trying to execute
    `configure' itself.

   Running `configure' takes awhile.  While running, it prints some
    messages telling which features it is checking for.

---

When I do the './configure' command it tries to open the file label configure in the directory and if I use 'sh ./configure' it doesn't recognise sh as a term. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions you're looking at are for Unix. On Windows, usually you'll want to follow the Windows installation instructions:

https://github.com/google/protobuf#c-installation---windows

As an exception, you'll want to follow the Unix instructions if you plan to use MinGW or Cygwin as your compiler (rather than Visual Studio). In these cases, you'll want to use the MSYS shell (for MinGW) or the Cygwin shell to run the commands in the instructions, not the regular Windows command prompt.